# How to skip java reserve keyword identifier check in tomcat

Tags: tomcat7

how to skip identifier check in tomcat.
Attribute names in EL expressions that clash with reserved keywords in Java. so to skip that check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add this line in catalina.properties for skip check for java reserve keywords.

**org.apache.el.parser.SKIP_IDENTIFIER_CHECK=true**